# Phonegap build error on com.android.support:support-v4

Tags: cordova, adobe

He guys need your help on this phonegap build below:

```
 -build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 20.0.0
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for MyApp...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 5.0.1
[gettarget] API level:        21
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/bin
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/bin/res
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/bin/rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/bin/rsLibs
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/gen
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/bin/classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/bin/dexedLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for MyApp...

>BUILD FAILED
/home/ec2-user/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:573: ../../../../../../home/ec2-user/android-sdk/com.android.support:support-v4:+ resolve to a path with no project.properties file for project /project

Total time: 0 seconds
```

Already tried searching for answer for this but nothing worked so far.

Comment: Seems like the new version fix mine: 

    <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin" version="2.5.0" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same error, only when I try to use the "com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin" plugin.
If I discard this from the config.xml file, the error disappears.

Comment: When I used 2.4.0 version of this plugin, he compiled properly.

Comment: Seems like the new version fix mine: 

    <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin" version="2.5.0" />

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error may be this is the Phonegap build server issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the problem today after installing cordova-plugin-local-notification

I would get the following when building my cordova app

*A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v4:+.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml
>            https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/
>        Required by:
>            :android:unspecified*

I ran the android sdk manager.

And selected Android Support Repository in Extras for installation(Android support library was already installed).

Then it worked after the installation...